# Get the full path of image from server

Tags: html, c#-4.0, html-parsing

I want to extract the image from server and store it in my local system. The image is displayed as background in `<img>` tag. How to extract and store the image. The actual image tag is given below

```
<img style="background:Url('..//contactdetails?data=4512354367432554')" src="some transparent image"/>
```

In the above tag image is being displayed as background and src contains some transparent image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform a request for the image and then save it on your machine.
First get the URI of the image:

```
var html = @"<img style=""background:Url('..//contactdetails?data=4512354367432554')"" src=""some transparent image""/>";
var regex = new Regex(@"//(?<Path>[^']+)'", RegexOptions.Singleline)
var uri = regex.Match(html).Groups["Path"].Value;
```

**EDIT**

If you are using `HtmlAgilityPack` (given that you already extracted the `a` tag) you can use the `Attributes` collection to get the `style` attribute and perform a match against the regular expression or you can use directly the `OuterHtml` property to match against the pattern like this:

```
var anchorTag = YourCodeToGetTheAnchorTag();
var attribute = anchorTag.Attributes["style"];
var match = regex.Match(attribute.Value);
var uri = match.Groups["Path"].Value;
```

Or, using the `OuterHtml` property:

```
var anchorTag = YourCodeToGetTheAnchorTag();
var match = regex.Match(anchorTag.OuterHtml);
var uri = match.Groups["Path"].Value
```

Next, concatenate the uri of the image to the directory from server, and create a request:

```
var fullUri = "http://www.example.com/" + uri;
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fullUri);
```

Get the response and save the image:

```
var response = request.GetResponse();
var image = Image.FromStream(response.GetResponseStream());
image.Save("path-on-your-machine");
```

Comment: Thank you RePierre, I'm using htmlagilitypack to extract. Can you show how to do it in c#. I tried modifying your code and using but its not working.